# Hibernate update call generates new row in @OneToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

So I have the following classes in my package

Class StoredData:

```
@Data
@Entity
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "data")
@Builder
public class StoredData {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "data_id", nullable = false)
private String dataId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "data", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private StoredSource source;
}
```

Class StoredSource:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id","data"})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "source_type")
@Table(name = "source")
public abstract class StoredSource {
 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "source_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private SourceType sourceType;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "data_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private StoredData data;

}
```

Now further 2 classes extends StoredSource Class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@DiscriminatorValue(SourceType.ADS_TEXT)
public class StoredAdSource extends StoredSource {

@Column(name = "ad_id")
private String adId;
 
}

@Data
@Entity
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@DiscriminatorValue(SourceType.OFFERS_TEXT)
public class StoredOfferSource extends StoredSource {

@Column(name = "offer_id")
private String offerId;

}
```

So now I already have an entry in my db in the source table as:

| source_type | id | ad_id | data_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADS | 1 | Ads12 | 1 |

But when I try to do an update to storedData object as:

```
StoredData storedData = getEntryFromDb();    
storedData.setSource(newData.getSource());
storedData.getSource().setData(storedData);
where newData is a StoredData type of object and only the ad_id of its source is changed to Ads1234.
```

Hibernate generates a new row as follows

| source_type | id | ad_id | data_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADS | 1 | Ads12 | 1 |
| ADS | 2 | Ads1234 | 1 |

I am unable to figure out why this is the case. Is it something due to the fact that StoredSource is an abstract class? Please help me out here.

Comment: do you need both mappings StoredData in StoredSource and StoredSource in StoredData? Could you remove one of them? If this is not possible try to remove cascade = CascadeType.ALL from StoredData member of StoredSource.

Comment: Yes I need both mappings. Also I tried removing cascade = CascadeType.ALL but still the same issue.